# How to execute very long SQL statement from sql file in visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010

I have to update my Database from very long `csv` file. I generate very long sql statement and I try to execute it directly in Visual Studio but it rised an error because Visual Studio can't take such long queries.

SQL file content :

```
INSERT INTO [HotelFacilitySet]
VALUES ('SPA');
```

Could any body explain how to execute `.sql` file from Visual Studio.

Thanks.

Comment: That's the query you are trying to run?

Comment: It just a sample, file is around 100mb.

Comment: What error do you get in Visual Studio?

Comment: you want to do that programmatically?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/43e8bc3a-1132-453b-b950-09427e970f31/run-a-sql-script-file-in-c?forum=adodotnetdataproviders

Comment: Skip VS and use command line to import into your database.

Comment: what exactly does the CSV file contain? you say the CSV file is big but then provide a sample of a 'SQL' file

Answer (score 1):

For such a large dataset, I would recommend loading the .sql file using bcp. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337544.aspx

Answer (score 0):

there are countless solutions for this depending on the actual content of the CSV file, and how often this needs to occur.(i will assume this only needs to occur once).

1. the import data Wizard built into SSMS
2. Integration services
3. some small script

personally i would choose the 1st option first and try my luck with the wizard although i would expect this to not work with a large file size such as this.

next i would try the third option and write a c# script to read through the file and import periodically.

it does depend on the actual content of the CSV however

Answer (score 0):

I have never had luck trying to load files in using any of the built-in options in SQL server. Maybe others have, but I've tried several times on about every version of SQL server since 2008, and no luck (one of the many reasons why SQL Server sucks).

That being said, my go-to on this would be a stream reader on the CSV file coupled with insert statements.  Here is my pseudo-code:

```
//read file using FileStream and break into chunks of 250 items each (or maybe some other number depending on size of object)
//The key is that Chunkify needs to return an enumerable that reads the file as your code is executing.
var chunks = Chunkify(file);

foreach(var chunk in chunks)
{

var stmt = new StringBuilder("INSERT INTO [HotelFacilitySet] VALUES (");

//Each chunk is a set of items
foreach(item in chunk) {
  stmt.Append(item);
  stmt.Append("),(");
}
stmt.Append(")");    
ExecuteSql(stmt);

}
```